# Are equivalence classes closed under intersection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I prove whether the set of equivalence classes for some equivalence relation is closed under intersection; that is the intersection of equivalence classes is an equivalence class?

If you're asking why... I'm trying to prove that Every two equivalence classes $[x]$ and $[y]$ are either equal or disjoint but that problem I can solve. I just need to know whether countable intersection of equivalence classes is an equivalence class.

Comment: I think you're on the wrong track because if you take the fact that any two equivalent classes are either equal or disjoint as granted then your question is trivial. In any case, my own proof of this fact doesn't involve this question at all.

Comment: Pf: To prove that Every two equivalence classes [x] and [y] are either equal or disjoint I'll assume the intersection of the two equivalence classes is non-empty. Let z be an element of the intersection. Since equivalence classes are closed under intersection, z is an element of some equivalence class I'll call [z] which equals      [x] $\bigcap$ [y]. all elements of [z] are related to x and all elements of [z] are related to y. it follows that [z]=[x] and [z]=[y]. by transitivity, [x]=[y]. @ProjectBook Did you see where I used equivalence classes are closed under intersection?

Comment: [z]=[x] $\bigcap$ [y] by definition.

Comment: is the union of equivalence classes a equivalence class?

Comment: It suffices to say that $z \in [x] \cap [y]$ implies that $\exists z \in [y]$ s.t. $w = z$ ($=$ denotes the equivalent relation) for all $w \in [x]$ hence $[x] \subset [y]$ by maximality of $[y]$ and similarly $[y] \subset [x]$ hence $[x] = [y]$.

Comment: why invent a new variable w if we could have said z is an element of y and x hence [x] is a subset of [y]?

Comment: Yes you could simply say that. It really depends on how pedantic you want to be. But in any case you see that all that is needed is $[x] \subset [y]$ and $[y] \subset [x]$.

Comment: This isn't true, so it can't be proved. Two equivalence classes may be disjoint. In that case their intersection is the empty set, and equivalence classes are non-empty, so the intersection is not an equivalence class in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is two show that if $[x]$ and $[y]$ are two classes, then they are the same or disjoint. This is easy to prove directly and does not necessitate us to consider arbitrary or countable intersections of classes at all:

Suppose $z \in [x] \cap [y]$ so that $[x]$ and $[y]$ are *not* disjoint.
Then in fact $[x] = [y]$:

Pick $u \in [x]$, so $u \sim x$ (where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation).
We also have $z \in [x]$ (so $z \sim x$ and also $x \sim z$ by symmetry) and $z \in [y]$, so $z \sim y$.

So $u \sim x \sim z \sim y$, so the properties of an equivalence relation tell us that $u \in [y]$. As $u$ was arbitrary $[x] \subseteq [y]$.

The proof that $[y] \subseteq [x]$ is entirely symmetric. So the classes are equal when they're not disjoint.

In words: If there is some $z$ equivalent to both $x$ and $y$, then everything equivalent to $x$ is equivalent to $y$ and vice versa.

Another way to see it: If you know that $x \sim y$ iff $[x] = [y]$ then
$z \in [x] \cap [y]$ implies $[x] = [z] = [y]$ quite directly.

All of this implies that the intersection of two classes already need not be a class, whenever there are two non-equivalent points $x \not \sim y$, so that $[x] \neq [y]$ and $[x] \cap [y] = \emptyset$ which is **not** a class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, yes, the intersection of classes is a class. It will either be empty if you are intersecting inequivalent classes or , if not, it will agree with the first class in your intersection, which will coincide, (intersection being non-empty) with all classes being intersected..

Comment: ...and the empty set is an equivalence class? According to what definition?

Comment: Never said it and does not follow from what I said. I described the possible outcomes. Still, if you want to penalize me for something I did not say, I guess that is your choice and nothing I can do about it.

Comment: what you did say (exact quote) is: "yes, the intersection of classes is a class".  The intersection of classes may be the empty set. Not interested in a meaningless dispute beyond this point.

Comment: Yes, if there are classes intersecting , then there is a class. Otherwise you get an empty set. That is the answer to the meaningless point you made and its associated downvote. No allowances for different forms of expression. Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If they are either equal or disjoint, then that means the (2-ary) intersection is either one set or the nullset. It is easily shown that this is also true for a k-ary intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are asking...

But if you are saying $R_1$ is an equivalence relation
and $R_2$ is an equivalence relation, is $R_1$ and $R_2$ an equivalence relation.

It is.  To prove it, show that it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

A partition is an equivalence relation.  And a sup-partition is still a partition.  So, pictorally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be any set with equivalence relations $R_1$ and $R_2$ defined on it.

• $R_1 \cap R_2:$

### Reflexive:

Since $R_1$ and $R_2$ are  both  reflexive,  then $$\forall x \in A:(x,x) \in R_1 \wedge (x,x) \in R_2.$$
Therefore, $(x,x) \in R_1 \cap R_2,$ so it is reflexive.

### Symmetric:

Let  $(x, y)\in R_1 \cap R_2.$ Then $(x,y) \in R_1$ and $(x,y) \in R_2.$ Since both $R_1$ and $R_2$ are symmetric, we have $(y,x) \in R_1$ and $(y,x) \in R_2.$ Therefore, $(y,x) \in R_1 \cap R_2,$ and the intersection is symmetric.

### Transitive:

Let $(x, y),(y,z) \in R_1 \cap R_2.$ Then, since $R_1$ and $R_2$ are both transitive, we have $(x,z) \in R_1$ and $(x,z) \in R_2.$ So, $(x,z) \in R_1 \cap R_2$ and the intersection is transitive.

This shows that $R_1 \cap R_2$ is an equivalence relation. That is, equivalence relations on a set $A$ are closed under intersection.